# Call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator(). Inside a .cpp file

Tags: c++

I declared a class and then an object, but when I want to use my object, it gives me an error. I searched a bit on Google, but didn't understand what my problem is.  The way I declared my class / object is the same as I usually do, and this is the first time it doesn't work.

Here's my `.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h++"

int game_loop(void)
{
    char *nam;
    Hero *myHero = new Hero();

    printf("So what's your name ? : ");
    scanf("%s", &nam);
    myHero->name(nam); //the error is here
}
```

and my `.h++`:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Hero
{
    public:
        std::string name;
        int race;
        int classe;
        int level = 0;
        int hp = 10;
        int mana = 5;
};
```

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: what do you expect `myHero->name(nam);` to do? `std::string` indeed does not have an `operator()`

Comment: it's in the title but i'll add it in the post

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i want to convert my char * that scanf gives me into a string and i saw on google that one of the way to do it was like that

Comment: The error message says you are treating `myHero->name` like a function, but it is neither a function nor a function-like class.

Comment: do you want to assign `nam` to `hero->name`? That would be `hero->name = nam;`. You should read about constructors and stay away from `new` and raw pointers. `char* nam` should be `std::string name;` and `Hero *myHero = new Hero();` should be `Hero myHero;`

Comment: so i can put a std::string in scanf ?

Comment: [OT]: Better to not use `new` here: `Hero myHero; std::cin >> myHero.name;` would do the job.

Comment: You probably should not use scanf or printf

Comment: @SirTristanus You misunderstood the example. You could *create* a string with `std::string name(nam)`, but you can't assign to it like that. To assign a value, you use assignment; `myHero->name = nam;`. Get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - learning by googling is extremely time consuming. (And stay away from C.)

Comment: no, i just forgot to mention: Don't mix C i/o in your C++ code, unless you know what you are doing. Use `std::cin`

Comment: ok ok thanks a lot guys i understood my error !

Comment: You may want this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) if you use getline please read this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) because you may want to use it and also use `cin >> someVariable`

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned the Undefined Behavior in this code due to using `scanf()` with an uninitialized `char*` pointer. `scanf("%s")` does not allocate memory, it must be given a pointer to a pre-existing buffer to fill in, eg: `char nam[256]; scanf("%256s", nam);`. Otherwise, some platforms support a non-standard `"%ms"` extension to let `scanf()` allocate a new buffer, eg: `char *nam; scanf("%ms", &nam); ... free(nam);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first thing's first, you are trying to use the `operator()` of a member of type `std::string`. That operator indeed does not exist.

If you want to set the value of `hero->name` to `nam`, you'd have to do something like this:

```cpp
hero->name = std::string(nam);
```

Second - why are you using C methods in C++? Using `scanf()` to input strings is unsafe. You should use `fgets()`, or C++'s own `std::cin`.

Comment: thanks a lot it was my problem

Comment: Or simpler: `hero->name = nam;` since `std::string` has an `operator=` for `const char*`.